# ASP.NET MVC - How to pass a Javascript variable from view to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable in a javascript function which needs to be sent to the controller. This is the code in the javascript function.

```
var testString = "Test";

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetJavaScriptString")",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(testString),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
        });
```

And this is the controller method

```
    public ActionResult GetJavaScriptString(string data)
    {

        return null;
    }
```

The variable "data" in the GetJavaScriptString method remains null.

Comment: Its `data: { data: testString },` (not `data: JSON.stringify(testString),`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a name/value pair when the name matches the name of your parameter

```
var testString = "Test";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetJavaScriptString")",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { data: testString }, // change this 
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

**Note** that you do not need `JSON.stringify()`, but if you did it would be `data: JSON.stringify({ data: testString }),` and you would need to the `contentType: 'application/json',` option

Comment: No its not (and you would know that if you tested it)

Comment: Read my comment in the question

Comment: I know its now correct - you just copied my code! And your first sentence is still an incorrect statement

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not copying your code. can you please modify as your way.